# Layout XML Issue - Magento EE 1.14

Tags: magento

I am currently having issues in setting a custom template for my home page in the latest version of Magento EE 1.14, I am using the following xml to change the page.

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/home-page.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>  
  </cms_index_index>
```

However this doesnt change anything, if i put the inside piece of code into the page in Magento CMS, then it works as expected.

Comment: What XML file are you putting this in?

Comment: Have added it into theme/default/layout/local.xml